# How to enable kerberos authentication to a Java web app

Tags: linux, java-7, kerberos

I'm currently using Centrify to aid with Kerberos/AD integration in our environment. Right now we have Kerberos enabled on a Centrified version of Apache. We are trying to run jnlp files through javaws and are having problems with passing Kerberos credentials along.

I have enabled Kerberos in the about:config section of Firefox and am able to pass authentication to apache, but get stopped at an "Authentication Required" screen from Java saying "Enter you login details to access on ." This same Window also says "Authentication Scheme: Integrated Windows"

How can I ensure these Kerberos credentials are passed to Java? At this point I don't even think Java is listening for Kerberos, so maybe the key is enabling this feature, however, I'm not sure how to go about doing this.

I'm running jdk-1.7.0_u51 and trying to connect to Apache from a Fedora 19 desktop.